# How do I profile ShowDialog?

Tags: c#, profiling, keyboard-hook, performance

I took over a Keyboard hook project and have been sprucing it up a bit. It used to be just 4 forms that had all the logic and maths in those 4 files. So *MANY* hours later I just about got the program back together after decoupling everything. The latest bit is by using the Model-View-Presenter design concept on the main window. All my tests work great on my machine, and naturally the program performs like it should on the target computers.

The target computers are simple x86 Intel Atom processors with 2gb of ram. They have buttons on them that correlate to F13-F18 on a keyboard (that is where my keyboard hook program comes into play). My development PC is a semi-stout 6-core AMD x64 machine with 8gb of ram. One thing I wanted to do was test out a way of setting those Function buttons to a particular task. All my unit tests pass for this portion. When I click on a new task type it works as desired.

"Cool", I say, "Lets see it in action" so i hit run in Visual Studio. I my program that F9-F12 are the keys to hook. Now the assignment window only opens up when you press one of the hooked keys when the main window is open. If that main window is not open then the task is performed. So I open my main window and hit F9 and the Assignment window shows but i can't click on anything for about 4 seconds. Then it "catches" up and does what ever I clicked on. I thought maybe it was my debugger so i went to the bin folder and ran the application directly and same deal.

I thought maybe it was a permissions thing so I ran as admin and same problem. I wondered how bad it would be on the target computers. I copied my bin folder to a flash drive, copied the content into Program Files and ran it. It worked great (well to a certain degree) But the problem was not present. I can select any task I want immediatly after the dialog is visible.

One strange thing is though that my keyboard hook stops working after 11 times of trying to reassign it...but that is a separate question. So i thought I remember someone saying, use a profiler. Well my visual studio had one so I turned it on but i can't make heads or tails of the data returned. I'd post code, but I don't know what to post. I even went as far as using `System.Console.Write(".");`  around the area I thought was the problem but that wasn't the problem

```
protected override void theHook_RegisteredKeyPressed(System.Windows.Forms.Keys key)
{
    if (TakeOver)
    {
        if (!Busy)
        {
            busy = true;
            LibraryTrace.Start("NewKeyAssignment", key);
            using (var window = new AssignmentTypePanel())
            {
                presenter = new TaskPresenter(window, theList[key].Task);
                window.Presenter = presenter;
                //execution will not continue past here until window is closed
                window.ShowDialog();
            }
            theList[key] = new TaskKey(key, presenter.Task);
            LibraryTrace.End("NewKeyAssignment", theList[key].Task.ToString());
            busy = false;
        }
   }
   else
   {
       base.theHook_RegisteredKeyPressed(key);
   }
}
```

So i'm stuck. I can't figure out what to type, what to ask. Any tips on how i can find the root of this problem?

Comment: well as a hunch I set all the target platforms to x86 and the problem still persists..  :/ The program has a 7MB memory footprint. (that is TaskManager says it is only using 7mb) and the program itself is only 1.1mb. strange how all the components work good by them selves, but not well together

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with an application i developed using winforms- the 'server-side' operation was lightning-quick, but still the form showing the results took ~5 seconds to show.
Upon investigation, it turns out that winforms has some known performance issues.
There are some suggestions for optimization (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59479/optimize-windows-form-load-time) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885041/how-to-load-a-winforms-app-quickly) and a few others i've found at the time but can't seem to locate right now).

Actually, none of them helped in my case.
I ended up realizing that the real bottleneck was creating and displaying a new form; what I ended up doing was a bit of a hack-
I placed ALL of my controls on the main form, with some of them hidden, and simulated a change of forms by hiding some controls and displaying others.
It's quite ugly, and won't scale up, but worked very well in my case.

Comment: interesting thoughts. I find it so strange that I'm having this many problems with all my tests passing. If i open the one form to assign a key manually (from a unit test) it works just fine. I keep trying to narrow down where the problem is. I am going mad about this. I think i'm going to work on another project for a day and see if that helps.